# Install python 3.6 virtualenv without modifying my python 3.5 installation

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, python-3.6

I use debian and I have python 3.5.3 installed. I am going to work on a project which requires python 3.6, but the last time I installed python 3.6 on my computer it broke a lot of things, so I would like to avoid that. What I want is to create a virtual environment which runs python 3.6, but without affecting my python 3.5 installation.

I know that the virtualenv command has an option to specify which python to use, but this would only work if I have a python 3.6 executable on my computer. Is there a way to install the virtualenv without having the python 3.6 executable installed ? If not, is it possible to install python 3.6 without getting rid of python 3.5 ?

In case you're wondering, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332641/how-to-install-python-3-6) is the procedure I followed to install python 3.6, which broke a bunch of stuff. Since then I've re-installed my OS for other reasons, and now I'm back on python 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interested in knowing how else to do this. But I personally use `conda`.

You can create other Python environments without having to installing it first because it's included in the `anaconda` metapackage.

If you look at my default system you see that it's only Python 2 available.

```
$ cd /usr/bin/ | ls | grep python
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root       11224 Sep  1  2016 abrt-action-analyze-python
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root        7136 May  3  2017 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root           9 Dec  9 13:27 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root           7 Dec  9 13:27 python -> python2
```

If you have conda installed then you can use the below to create a venv, activate it, and then you see you're using a different Python that's not installed on your file system.

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
$ source activate py35
py35 $ python --version
Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). After you install pyenv, you can use something like the following to install a specific python version:

`pyenv install 3.6.4`

Then you can use this python version with `pyenv global`, `pyenv local`, or `pyenv virtualenv` commands.

Answer (score 0):

**Install supporting softwares**

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```

**Download required python version in the** `/tmp` **directory**

I'm assuming you are going to install Python 3.6.12

```
cd /tmp

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.6.12.tgz

tar -xf Python-3.6.12.tgz

cd Python-3.6.12.tgz
```

**Install python version**

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions

sudo make altinstall
```

**Note**

There are two ways to install python one is `altinstall` and the other one is  `install`

`altinstall` is the preferred method since it will not overwrite the existing default python version

Now since you followed `altinstall` method, In the terminal, you can see multiple python versions

```
>> python --version
Python 2.7.18

>> python3.5 --version
Python 3.5.10

>> python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.12
```

Now to create virtual environment of version 3.6

```
cd ~/home/location/

python3.6 -m venv <virtual_environment_name>

source virtual_environment_name/bin/activate
```